# Difference between visited and touched in Redux Form?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Using the Redux-form package in my React application, I noticed that the fields inside a Redux-form have visited and touched attributes. To me it looks like they both signify if the user has had focus on the form field. What is the difference between these two attributes with text inputs?

Comment: Looks like `visited` will only be set if you pass an `onFocus` prop: https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-meta-visited-boolean-code-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `redux-form` [documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/field.md/):

> **meta.touched : boolean**
>
> true if the field has been touched. By default this will be set when the field is blurred.
>
> **meta.visited: boolean**
>
> true if this field has ever had focus. It will only work if you are passing onFocus to your input element.

Comment: The documentation says it is true if the field has been touched, however what does touching mean in practice in this case?

Comment: Im guessing when the `onBlur` is called from the input props you pass in/native input component. So it triggers after the user leaves focus of the field.

Comment: Best way to find out is to run a small example/look at the source code, that is just my guess